# HTML JS onClick event not firing in iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios

I am working in a web project where user will be asker for input then clicking the button but button onClick event seems to dont work in iOS, works perfectly in Android devices.

```html
<div class="confess-div" id="cdiv">
        <div class="confess-select-group-button">
            <button class="active-button" id="sgroup" onclick="switchToSGroup()">Sabahçı grup</button>
            <button onclick="switchToOGroup()" id="ogroup">Öğlenci Grup</button>
        </div>
        <p class="confess-text">BİR İTİRAF YAZ</p>
        <textarea class="confess-textarea" id="confess-input" placeholder="Buraya yaz"></textarea>
        <div class="confess-send-button">
            <a onclick="sendConfess()" style="text-decoration: none;"><button>Gönder!</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="success" style="color: white; font-size: 200%; text-align: center; display: none;">GÖNDERİLDİ</p>
```

```js
function sendConfess(){
    var confessInput = document.getElementById("confess-input")
    var xarea = document.getElementById("cdiv")
    if(selectedGroup == 0x0){
        xfinal = "\n\nSABAHÇI GRUP -- "+confessInput.value
    }
    else{
        xfinal = "\n\nÖĞLENCİ GRUP -- "+confessInput.value
    }
    navigator_descriptor()
    fetch("WEBHOOKRUL", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "content" : navigator_descriptor() + "\n" + ipadress + xfinal
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
    xarea.style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("success").style.display="block"
}
}
```

I do not have a iOS device so i can't do anything